# How to take map values (key - value pairs), inside a list

Tags: list, go, interface, hashmap

I am stuck with this, I want to write 2 maps within the list. How do I do that? I tried this, but this doesn't work. Even instead of interface{}, I put string, it doesn't work.

```
var b := []interface{}{
        {
            "type" : "value1",
            "target" : "value2",
        },
        {
            "type" : "value3",
            "target" : "value4",
        }
}
```

Comment: Don't use `interface{}`.

Answer (score 2):

```golang
var b = []interface{}{
        map[string]string{
            "type":   "value1",
            "target": "value2",
        },
        map[string]string{
            "type":   "value3",
            "target": "value4",
        },
}
```

or, if `b` can be of type `[]map[string]string`

```golang
var b = []map[string]string{{
    "type":   "value1",
    "target": "value2",
}, {
    "type":   "value3",
    "target": "value4",
}}
```